# Модуль shelve генерирует на разных платформах разные файлы

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x, macos

При выполнении одной и той же команды, на разных платформах модуль [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shelve.html) генерирует файл(ы) с разными расширениями. Если же нужно более подробно:

```
s = shelve.open("test", writeback=True)
```

При выполнении вот такой команды, получается следующий результат:

1. На linux-base системах генерируется **один** файл с названием "test"
2. На MacOS генерируется **один** файл с названием "test.db"
3. На Windows генерируются **три** файла, каждый с названиями "test.dir", "test.dat" и "test.bak"

Этот факт печалит и сильно мешает работе кода с использованием чтения файла, сгенерированного с помощью модуля shelve на разных платформах.

В поисках ответа на вопрос: "Да как так-то?!", я наткнулся на вот [эту](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171833/why-does-the-shelve-module-in-python-sometimes-create-files-with-different-exten) страницу с англоязычного stackoverflow. Как я понял (а увы, мои познания в английском не столь велики), проблема в том, что модуль shelve использует (*основан на*) модуль anydbm, который, в свою очередь, является программным интерфейсом использования системных реализаций баз данных, таких как [dbhash](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dbhash.html), [gdbm](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gdbm.html), [dbm](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dbm.html) и [dumbdbm](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dumbdbm.html). Далее, на этой же странице указано, что реализация бд, которая генерирует **по три файла** - это dumbdbm.

Из всего, что я смог перевести на этой странице, я предположил, что проблема в несовместимости реализаций баз данных на разных системах. Я предпринял попытку установки gdbm на windows [отсюда](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gdbm.htm). Предпринял также попытку добавить папку, содержащую бинарники с gdbm в PATH, но этого видно не достаточно, чтобы shelve на windows могла читать shelve-файлы, которые сгенерированы в linux-base системе.

В общем, вопрос: как исправить сие недоразумение?

**UPD:** Вопрос старый, но ещё открытый. Добавлю: задача тогда была в том, чтобы вместе с объектом сериализовать ещё и его методы и перенести этот файл в другую ОСь

Comment: Если я где-то ошибся в рассуждениях, подправьте пожалуйста

Comment: А проблема в чем? Сохранили с помощью `shelve` - с его же помощью открывайте.

Comment: если так принципиально читать чем-то другим, определяйте платформу, расширения уже знаете. А так не понятно почему не читаете через shelve.open, если БД не корректна, он ее и не откроет на чтение\запись.

Comment: Вы неправильно меня поняли. Если я сгенерировал БД на linux и попытался с помощью shelve.open его открыть на винде - не получится. Python ругается. Тоже самое, если сгенерировать на винде и попытаться открыть в linux-base

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению файлы, генерируемые данным модулем, не кроссплатформенны, так что вкратце ответ на ваш вопрос - никак не исправить.

Я не знаю какая у вас задача, но если таковая сотоит в сериализации python структур данных и записи их в файл, то рассмотрите какие-то другие модули, которые подходят вам. Например, [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) или [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Также можно рассмотреть использование какой-либо бд, например, [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). Или [sqlite в связке с pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#persistence-of-external-objects). Все эти варианты являются кроссплатформенными.

Comment: Использование shelve схоже чем-то с использованием словарей. Задача стоит такая: ключ - идентификатор пользователя, значение - экземпляр кастомного класса.

Comment: @Semior через pickle.dumps должно работать. К базе тоже прикручивается без проблем. Рассмотрите этот вариант, думаю заработает